# Badge not showing up in "badges tab" concurrent with other pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On User Experience I've received the Editor Badge (and later the "student" badge). My username/rep/badges bit at the top of the screen was immediately updated to reflect this, and if went to [my profile](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/14165/gis-jonathan) they were showing up clearly under my gravatar.

However, when I click on [the badges tab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/14165/gis-jonathan?tab=badges) I didn't see any badges until about 5-6mins later.

But they did show up with a tick next to them on - https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges and they did appear on my activity - https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/14165/gis-jonathan?tab=activity - but for some reason the badges page took a very long time to update, despite reloading it quite a few times.

Comment: Caching. There are a lot of pages to update. It all takes time.

Comment: "in a timely manner" is entirely subjective.

Comment: @oded - that may have been poor wording. Improved now.

Comment: @ChrisF - That would make sense, except every other page seems to update much faster which is what made me notice it and why I reported it. 5+ mins is quite a long cache when everything else seems to get updated in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The badges page (`/badges`) and the badge counts you have at the top are *not* cached. Both of these update immediately once the system determines you've gained a badge.

On the other hand, your badges activity in your user profile *is* cached. It takes a while to update those, which includes the mini-box on the index of your profile. hey *usually* update fairly quickly (around 10 minutes for me on SO and MSO), but we all know that their caching system and how it updates is very complex. Sometimes it takes longer than expected... oh well. The system will always correct itself with time* so I wouldn't worry about it.

<sub>* Unless it's a *real* bug, but in this case it's not.</sub>